# calling from main.ps1 file to function that exist on second.ps1 file relatively in powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-core

I'm trying to call a function that exists on another ps1 file from my main ps1 file, the problem is that I can't do it dynamically,
example:
if I'm referencing ps1 file like this it's working very good:

```
. "C:\scripts\restoreDB1.0\QueryBuilder.ps1"
```

I want to do something like this:
`. "\QueryBuilder.ps1" or "QueryBuilder.ps1"` or

```
$ref1 = Join-Path  ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -ChildPath "QueryBuilder.ps1"
''+"$($ref1)"+''
```

since the files are in the same directory.

one more thing, I need it to work from any path (outside the project directory) on the local machin

tnx.

Comment: `. .\QueryBuilder.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

main.ps1

```bsh
param(
    [string] $nameOfScriptToDotSource = 'QueryBuilder.ps1'
)

. "$PSScriptRoot\$nameOfScriptToDotSource"

DoStuff
```

QueryBuilder.ps1

```bsh
function DoStuff() {
    Write-Host 'Doing stuff...'
}
```